# Is there a way to use a regular expression to match hosts in ansible?

Tags: regex, ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-bug

I am trying to match hosts using a regex pattern with ansible but it is not working as expected. 
My inventory is as seen below:

```
[group1]
hello1
world1
hello2
world2

[group2]
hello3
```

And my task is:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_inventory_hostnames:
    - ~hello*
```

From their documentation:

```
Using regexes in patterns
You can specify a pattern as a regular expression by starting the pattern with ~:

~(web|db).*\.example\.com
```

When I execute the task there is no output. I am a n00b with regex so could it be possible my regex is wrong?

Comment: `hello*` matches `hell`+ 0 or more `o`. You want `hello.*`. https://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html should give you the basics you need to learn to start.

Comment: There are 2 votes to close this question. They argue it's off-topic and not enough info. I think they are both wrong. It covers [software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and there is enough info to answer it. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q: ***"Could it be possible my regex is wrong?"***

A: It's a bug. See [inventory_hostnames lookup doesn't support wildcards in patterns #17268](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17268). It will be probably [fixed in 2.10](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/63858). But your pattern wouldn't work, I think, because the [doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) says: *`"You can use wildcard patterns with FQDNs or IP addresses, as long as the hosts are named in your inventory by FQDN or IP address"`*. The hosts in your inventory are neither FQDN nor IP.

Q: ***"Is there a way to use a regular expression to match hosts in ansible?"***

A: Yes. It is. A very convenient way is to create dynamic groups with the module [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-add-a-host-and-alternatively-a-group-to-the-ansible-playbook-in-memory-inventory). For example the playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: my_dynamic_group
      loop: "{{ groups.all|select('match', my_pattern)|list }}"
      vars:
        my_pattern: '^hello\d+$'

- hosts: my_dynamic_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
    "inventory_hostname": "hello2"
    "inventory_hostname": "hello1"
    "inventory_hostname": "hello3"
```

---

**Update**

The next option is the inventory plugin *constructed*. See

```bash
shall> ansible-doc -t inventory ansible.builtin.constructed
```

1. Create the inventory

```bash
shell> tree inventory/
inventory/
├── 01-hosts
└── 02-constructed.yml

0 directories, 2 files
```

```ini
shell> cat inventory/01-hosts 
[group1]
hello1
world1
hello2
world2

[group2]
hello3
```

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/02-constructed.yml 
plugin: ansible.builtin.constructed
groups:
  hello_group: inventory_hostname.startswith('hello')
  world_group: inventory_hostname.startswith('world')
```

2. Test the inventory

```bash
shell> ansible-inventory -i inventory --graph
@all:
  |--@group1:
  |  |--hello1
  |  |--hello2
  |  |--world1
  |  |--world2
  |--@group2:
  |  |--hello3
  |--@hello_group:
  |  |--hello1
  |  |--hello2
  |  |--hello3
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--@world_group:
  |  |--world1
  |  |--world2
```

You can see that the plugin created two groups: *world_group* and *hello_group*.

3. Use the groups. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: hello_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true

- hosts: world_group
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook  -i inventory pb.yml 

PLAY [hello_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [hello1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - hello1
  - hello2
  - hello3

PLAY [world_group] ***************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [world1] => 
  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - world1
  - world2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
hello1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
world1: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```